# Unwrap option missing from menu, how to enable it?

Tags: uv

newbie here. When I try to do Unwrap in UV layout, I can't because the option is missing from the menu bar.

I am in edit mode and I apply a new material image texture (jpg), but once I do that and go to UV layout to make the texture unwrap (or smart uv), the Unwrap option doesn't show up. The layer I am applying the texture on is a curve. How to enable the option?

P.S. I tried the shortcut A -> U, but still nothing.

I am using the latest mac version of Blender, 3.4.1 (3.4.1 2022-12-20)

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot of your whole interface?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Curve can't be UV unwrapped in the traditional way of using U menu >unwrap... If you want to use that, you need to convert the curve to mesh

Comment: @moonboots here you go https://imgur.com/a/sYEtkXQ it's a wall with a wooden texture (jpeg) that is distorted, and I am trying to unwrap it so it fits nicely to the shape. 
Emir, I believe that, but somehow I managed to do it once with this same shape being curve and not mesh?

Comment: For the moment you're not in Edit mode, so you can't see any UVs, switch to Edit mode and select all?

Comment: I think I am? https://imgur.com/a/kVqZfS7

Comment: Could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here you go [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=apPmybOA" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/apPmybOA/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object is a nurbs curve, not a mesh, you can't unwrap a nurbs curve. To convert to mesh, select it, right click > *Convert To > Mesh*, then unwrap.

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you, much appreciated.